# Routing to non-restfull controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a controller Sagepay, which have number of custom method (not RESTfull resources). How can I write routes for those actions? So far I tried:

```
namespace :sagepay, controller: :sagepay, as: :sagepay  do
  post :notification
  get :iframe_breaker
  get :accept_payment
end
```

This however tries mapping to `sagepay/sagepay_controller` instead simple `sagepay_controller`.

Obviously I can do this:

```
  match '/sagepay/notification' =>  'sagepay#notification', via: :post, as: sagepay_notification
  (etc)
```

which works, but this is not a solution I am looking for. Is there any way I can write it in common block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

```
scope 'sagepay', controller: :sagepay, as: :sagepay  do
  post :notification
  get :iframe_breaker
  get :accept_payment
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get `sagepay/sagepay_controller` is the reason why `namespace`s are used.  In order to get `sagepay/notification` you can define a resource and add `collection` routes within it, as follows:

```
# config/routes.rb
resource :sagepay, controller: :sagepay  do
  collection do 
    post :notification
    get :iframe_breaker
    get :accept_payment
  end
end
```

**Update:**

In order to define only the routes defined within the collection and avoid definition of the seven restful routes that Rails create you can pass in `only` option to the `resource` definition as follows:

```
# config/routes.rb
resource :sagepay, controller: :sagepay, only: []  do
  collection do 
    post :notification
    get :iframe_breaker
    get :accept_payment
  end
end
```

Comment: This will however also create '/sagepay/edit' and similar paths, won't it?

Comment: You can pass `only: []` option to `resource` to generate only the routes you define within the collection.

Comment: I agree and I thought about this. I am not really keen to define completely empty resource - this seems quite hacky, especially that I have no resource here.